# Plotting or time.sleep or csv saving datas in a while loop induces lags between sensed and read datas from a force sensor

Tags: python, matplotlib, serialization, serial-port, sensors

I am quite fresh using Python. I need it to acquire serial datas from a force sensor plugged into a COMPORT (6). With the code below, I have no problem to store the datas in a list and save it afterwards. I can also print each data without noticing any lag.

However, when I try to implement a plot in my while loop, a rather annoying shift appears between the time I touch my sensor and the datas are written (from few to tens of seconds). I first thought it was because matplotlib is a memory consuming library, but even when i add the simple line "time.sleep(0.00001), which is a very short pause compared to the rate of acquisition (60 FPS), I get the same lags. I also tried to save my datas in a csv file and plot the datas in a different function by using multiprocess but even saving datas triggers the lag also.

This is problematic as visualizing my live datas is an important part of my experiment.
Could someone please help me with this particular issue ?

Thank you so much.

````
import serial
import struct
import platform
import multiprocessing

import time
import numpy as np
import csv
# from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



class MeasurementConverter:
    def convertValue(self, bytes):
        pass


class ForceMeasurementConverterKG(MeasurementConverter):
    def __init__(self, F_n, S_n, u_e):
        self.F_n = F_n
        self.S_n = S_n
        self.u_e = u_e

    def convertValue(self, value):
        A = struct.unpack('>H', value)[0]
        # return (A - 0x8000) * (self.F_n / self.S_n) * (self.u_e / 0x8000)
        return self.F_n / self.S_n * ((A - 0x8000) / 0x8000) * self.u_e * 2


class GSV3USB:
    def __init__(self, com_port, baudrate=38400):
        com_path = f'/dev/ttyUSB{com_port}' if platform.system(
        ) == 'Linux' else f'COM{com_port}'
        # print(f'Using COM: {com_path}')
        self.sensor = serial.Serial(com_path, baudrate)
        self.converter = ForceMeasurementConverterKG(10, 0.499552, 2)



    def read_value(self):
        self.sensor.read_until(b'\xA5')
        read_val = self.sensor.read(2)
        return self.converter.convertValue(read_val)



   
            
# initialization of datas
gsv_data=[]
temps=[]
t_0=time.time()




def data_gsv():
    dev = GSV3USB(6)
    # fig=plt.figure()
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    i=0
    # line1, = ax.plot(temps, gsv_data)

    try:
        while True:
            

            gsv_data.append(dev.read_value())
            t1=time.time()-t_0
            temps.append(t1)
            
            
            # I can print the datas without noticing any lags
            print(dev.read_value())   
            # I cannot plot the datas without noticing any lags
            plt.plot(temps,gsv_data)
            plt.draw ()
            plt.axis([temps[i]-6,temps[i]+6,-2,10])
            plt.pause(0.00001)
            plt.clf()
            i=i+1
            # I cannot pause without noticing any lags
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            # I cannot save datas without noticing any lags
            with open('student_gsv.csv', 'w') as f: 
                write = csv.writer(f) 
                write.writerow(gsv_data)                 
            
 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting")
        return



if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_gsv()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop is constructed in a way that each time when you acquire a value with gsv_data.append(dev.read_value()), the plot is drawn again. That probably takes time, and if the data frequency with that the measuring device (GSV-3 USB) send measured data is quite high - let's say >10 frames/s - you'll get these "lags".

I would lower the plot update rate:

- append the measured data to an array (as you already do)
- Use a counter or a comparison of time difference to get a plot update rate of about 4 times per second (250ms). This is an update rate often used for being consumed by the human eye.